# Child's "add padding" on hover doesn't ignore parent's padding and text moves down

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a link hover affect where the background becomes white upon hover and the white background expands from the center (center to top, center to bottom).

The parent div element has an existing top/bottom padding of 24px, the inner link elements are therefore placed in the center of the div (24px from the top of the div). Upon the mouse hovering the link, the top/bottom padding for the link changes from the original 0px to 24px, supposedly increasing the child element (link)'s size to cover the entire parent div. At the same time, the child's background is changed to white, giving the animated affect.

However, when I tried this (see below), the top of the child element (link) stayed at the same place (I think to respect the parent's padding of 24px) instead of moving up, and the child element grew downward. As a result, the text (which is centered) moved downwards as well. Why doesn't the child ignore the parent's padding like in the example code below, and why doesn't the child grow both upward and downward from the original center?

Can anyone think of why this might be happening? I'm using the same code as below for the parent and children.

The code example I found online for doing this is attached below. It can also be seen as example 3 in this link:

https://codepen.io/Calloumi/pen/vndlH

Note: The demo below works. It's in my webpage (picture below) that the hover effect doesn't work.

[image]

Html:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
div {
  padding: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Raleway;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#nav-3 {
  background: #EEA200;
}

.link-3 {
  transition: 0.4s;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;

}
.link-3:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #EEA200;
  padding: 24px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-3">
    <a class="link-3" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="link-3" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="link-3" href="#">Contact</a>
    <a class="link-3" href="#">Shop</a>
</div>
```

Comment: _As a result, the text (which is centered) moved downwards as well_ ... The text seems to be fine (i.e., in your demo)

Comment: I don't see any issue. Is it already fixed during edit?

Comment: The code and the demo works. The problem is with my page in the picture. I tried the same code as the demo and it didn't work with my website. @AmitMankotia

Comment: And the question was: "Can anyone think of why this might be happening?" -- Why the problem described above might have happened for me (picture) and not in the demo, that is. @emineminems